The Celestial Mr. Harrison

Clues:
Wow! [in red] with red oval encompassing number 2, black circle around 3, and the numbers 1 and 4.
Group of 18 black circles with numbers in a matrix.
Top Row: [6, _, 36, 23, blood drop, 145]
Second Row: [ _, _, 23, 3, 12, 135]
Third Row: [ _, _, _, _, 4, _]
Group of letters and 3 large arcs over the silhouette of a city, with the words "FOLLOW ME" between the arcs.
Instructions: Name That Actor
_ _ _ _ _ _ E _ _ _ _ _
Hint 1

 That blood has been there a while. It should be firm to the touch.

Hint 2

 Any Buckeyes fans here?

Hint 3

 Specifically, Buckeyes fans from the late 70s.

Hint 4:

 

Hint 5:

 Meanwhile 


If you weren’t the person who originally made this puzzle, please provide proper attribution. Otherwise, feel free to ignore this comment.

@TheEmptyStringPhotographer, this is  his 35th question (all in the same style). I am sure he knows how this site works.

@Lezzup I understand, but the image makes it look like it was taken from another site, especially the difficulty stars. I guess you’re right, though.

Hint 1 and 4 are obviously rot13(oenvyyr), even though that was kind of obvious based on the puzzle structure, plus hint 1 clued that enough. Not to be rude, but that seems like the wrong thing to hint on… the rest of the puzzle seems much harder

answer:

NOEL FIELDING

solution:

 As stated by other commentators, the top left refers to the wow signal. Reading numbers in order gives 1561.
 The part below is braille. For each number 1-6, look at all dots that contain that number and read those as braille. This gives "G IB GE M D AAA". Noticing that this contains a lot of low letters, convert those to digits to get "7 92 75 M 4 111". Use periodic table to get "N U RE M BE RG", or "Nuremberg".
 Combine this with the 1561 from the Wow signal to get https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1561_celestial_phenomenon_over_Nuremberg
 This article comes with an illustration. Importantly, this illustration perfectly lines up with the lines and cityscape on the right side. Overlay the 2 images:



From here, you can notice that if you read the red circles from right to left (as indicated by the arrow), you can read "DRINKBAILEYSFROMASHOE". "Drink Bailey's from a shoe" refers to a quote said by Old Gregg from the show "The Mighty Boosh", a character played by Noel Fielding, the answer. As confirmation, the character is also nicknamed "The Moon", which is what the "FOLLOW ME" text was on top of in the overlay.

OP Edits:

 Several times in the translated text from the illustration it mentions the color of blood, tying back to the blood drop.


 The translated text states that the giant black arrow points West. Given that the sun rises in the East and sets in the West, by following the Sun - right to left - using red circles, we get the statement identified.


On Mighty Boosh, Noel Fielding also plays Tony Harrison, an octopus head thing with tentacles.


Partial Guess: [Waiting for any further hints]

Charlie Sheen

Reasoning:

The signal is called Wow Signal, discovered in 1977 [around the 1970s, as goes the buckeyes fan reasoning. Moreover, Charlie Sheen played the role named Zane Zaminsky in the film Arrival (1996), which is based on this WOW Signal. I could not relate the blood drops and the line 'FOLLOW ME' over the silhouette of the city.]

I am working on it.

The Wow Signal numbers seem to give the number "1561" and the Braille seems to give "G IB GE M D AAA". The only meaning I can see that having is the Gibbering Gemstone from Diablo III (GIB GEM D3) but I'm not sure. I have no clue what the skyline is of unfortunately, but maybe GIBGEMDAAA is for the letter grid?

Did you get the braille part from hint 4? It says Can you read this here.

it's quite obvious without hint 4? 3-row even-column set of circles is pretty clearly braille. Hint 1 makes this even more obvious if you didn't get it at that point. Hint 4 was complete overkill from the creator, they're not cluing the right parts

I know its braille. But it does not seem to read G IB GE M D AAA, as I can see. Would you please elaborate a bit?

for each digit from 1-6, look at all circles containing that corresponding number and treating those as braille. The blood should be treated as present for all. Doing so gives 1 = G, 2 = IB, 3 = GE, 4 = M, 5 = D, 6 = AAA.

Perhaps try the braille numbers instead?

There have been too many hints on braille, I guess? Any thing related to the silhouette of the city? That seems confusing...
